# Get texture from IResult - Facebook SDK Unity 7.1.0

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I try to get user avatar from facebook after login successfully.
I used to use "FBResult.Texutre"
But it seems texture property in IResult or IGraphResult is not provided in new sdk version.
Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution for it:

- Add `using UnityEngine;
  Texture2D Texture { get; }` to IGraphResult.cs
- Add `public Texture2D Texture { get; private set; }` to GraphResult.cs
- Add `this.Texture;` to GraphResult constructor in GraphResult.cs

Now you can get Texture from IGraphResult

Example:

```
void GetAvatar(IGraphResult result){ ... result.Texture ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the [latest version of the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity). Simply use the Texture field from IGraphResult.

```
FB.API("/me/picture", HttpMethod.GET, delegate(IGraphResult result) {
  if (result.Texture != null) {
    // use texture
  }
});
```